# Why circular list doesn't solve Josephus problem?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, circular-list, josephus

I am working on the program which solves [Josephus problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem) on C. I have to use circular linked lists here. Currently I have this code to create list:

```
void create_list(int N, struct node* head){
    int i, j, k;
    for(i = 2; i <= N; i++){
        struct node* tmp_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        tmp_node -> number = i;
        tmp_node -> next = NULL;
        tmp_node -> next = head -> next;
        head -> next = tmp_node;
        head = tmp_node;
    }
  }
```

Now I am working on finding last element to remin after Josephus permutations. I have this:

```
int find_last(int M, struct node* head){
    int i, j = 1;

    if(head -> next == NULL){
        return head -> number;
    }
    else {
        struct node* current = head;
        while(current -> next != NULL){
            while(current -> next -> number != j){
                current = current -> next;
                j++;
            }
            if (j % M == 0){
                struct node* delete_node;
                delete_node = current -> next;
                current -> next = delete_node -> next;
                free(delete_node);
                j = 1;
            }
        }
        return current -> number;
    }
}
```

And this is my main:

```
int main(){
    int M, N, i, j, res;
    struct node* head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head -> number = 1;
    head -> next = NULL;
    read_numbers(&N, &M);
    create_list(N, head);
    res = find_last(M, head);
    printf("%d\n", res);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The problem occurs in *int find_last* function. Please, tell me the errors and what I can do to solve the problem, thanks for your time.

EDIT.

I have drawn the algorithm and updated my function but it still doesn't work. Here it is:

```
int find_last(int M, int N, struct node* head){
    int i = 0, j = 1;

    if(head -> next == NULL){
        return head -> number;
    }
    else {
        struct node* current = head;
        while(i != N){
            while(j % M != 0){
                current = current -> next;
                j++;
            }
            struct node* delete;
            delete = current -> next;
            delete -> next = current -> next;
            free(delete);
            i++;
        }
        return current -> number;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Fe2O3
but I tested that funtion by printing all of the elements, it worked. Can you, please, explain it in details?

Comment: What's "circular" about this LL?

Comment: @Fe2O3
 Circular means that last element is connected to the first one.

Comment: Time to get out pencil and paper and sketch what's happening in `create_list()`. Be careful about the ever changing value of `head`...

Comment: @Fe2O3 here I have written all of that: [link](https://wbd.ms/share/v2/aHR0cHM6Ly93aGl0ZWJvYXJkLm1pY3Jvc29mdC5jb20vYXBpL3YxLjAvd2hpdGVib2FyZHMvcmVkZWVtLzdlZDFmNzA3MDM4ODQwM2ViYjkwOWNmODMwNmZmYzJjX0JCQTcxNzYyLTEyRTAtNDJFMS1CMzI0LTVCMTMxRjQyNEUzRF80ZGZmMGQzMS0xZjg4LTRjOWQtYjQ1OC01NmU4ZGQwYjgzM2I=)

Comment: Just minor cosmetics: It's meaningless to assign `NULL` to a pointer if you re-assign the same one right the next expression anyway – in best case the compiler optimises away the double assignment otherwise it even costs runtime, in any case you get less readable code (having to read obsolete instructions).

Comment: Wait a second, your function is named `find_last`, but id does potentially delete nodes??? Absolutely *do* rename it, this is something no-one would ever expect from that name!

Comment: You seem never to use `i`, so remove it.

Comment: @Aconcagua
OK, thanks.

Comment: `N` and `M` are not ideal names, they do not really tell what the variables stand for. Looks like `N` is the number of nodes you want to eliminate (side note: if you want to leave only one single node anyway, you don't need `N` at all; as your list is circular you can detect the last node on `current == current->next`…) and `M` obviously is the out-counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`create_list()` does NOT create a circular LL. You'll have to examine the code to see your own mistake there. The shortest explanation would take longer to relate than merely fixing the code.

Shorter (working!) code to study:

```
typedef struct n { // typedef reduces verbiage
    int no; // simple, short and sweet name for variables
    struct n *next;
} node;

node *create( int N ) { // simple function name
    node *pHead = NULL, *pTail = NULL; // track head & tail of LL

    for( int i = 1; i <= N; i++ ) { // make N nodes
        node *pn = malloc( sizeof *pn ); // no casting, and sizeof tied to variable, not type
        // Omitting verification for brevity
        pn->no = i; // assign the value

        if( !pTail )
            pHead = pTail = pn; // first node
        else
            pTail = pTail->next = pn; // linking onto end
    }
    return pTail->next = pHead; // May the circle be unbroken!!
}

int killOff( int M, node *pn ) { // NB: function name tells all

    while( pn->next != pn ) { // until only "self" remains
        for( int i = M; --i; ) pn = pn->next; // skip M nodes around circle
        node *del = pn->next;
        pn->next = del->next; // dead man walking in exile now
        free( del ); // bye bye
    }
    return pn->no; // survivors ID
}

int main( void ) {
    int M = 3, N = 17; // constants

    node *head = create( N ); // simple, right?

    printf( "Survivor: %d\n", killOff( M, head ) ); // simpler, too!

    free( head ); // kill off the last of them

    return 0; // and good night
}
```

You can get yourself tied up in knots with verbiage and without planning.

Caveat: `M` down count may be off-by-one. Change `--i` to `i--` to suit your interpretation of how far to travel around the shrinking ring of nodes.

**EDIT**
After closer examination, I believe the following is a better version. (No changes to `create()` shown above.)

```
int killOff( int M, node *pn ) {
    // the previous "victim" is #0 at the start of each iteration
    // So, the first iteration begins with 1; subsequent iterations with 0
    for( int i = 1; pn->next != pn; i = 0 ) {
        while( ++i < M ) pn = pn->next;
        node *del = pn->next;
        pn->next = pn->next->next;
        free( del );
    }
    int survivorID = pn->no;
    free( pn ); // Last "survivor" is free'd here, remembered only by "name."
    return survivorID;
}

int main( void ) {
    printf( "Survivor: %d\n", killOff( 3, create( 17 ) ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will compare codes to see the error.

Comment: Suggest you add as many "print debugging" statements as you need to both versions... Try a "restricted" print statement that goes M+4 nodes around the "loops" of both versions. You'll see that your version is not a circular LL... Learning can be tough, but it's worth climbing all the mountains one can! Cheers! `:-)`

Comment: Thanks dude, it really worked. I didn't fully copy your solution but compared them and figured out errors. Thank you again